# objWORD.Quit not closing created Word object

Tags: excel, vba, windows-10, exit, excel-2013

Within some of my VBA code, I create a Word object, open a Word file, close said Word file, quit Word object, and set both to nothing. Until "Recently", exactly when, I do not know, I have been pulled different directions in the past 2-3 months, it has been working fine.
However "the other day", my code started hanging up - spinny wheel, couldn't click/edit any cells, etc. - on these files, specifically during Word operations.

When i opened Task Manager, I noticed hidden instances of MS Word open. when I closed those via Task Manager, my Excel file would come back to normal.

for clarity, a sample of my typical code is below (revised per comments):

```vb
Dim objWORD as Object
Dim fileWORD as Object
Dim filenameWORD as String
'Other variables, etc

filenameWORD = "\\someUNCpath\Folder\File.docx"

Set objWORD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set fileWORD = objWORD.Documents.Open(filenameWORD)

'Do the stuff to the thing

fileWORD.Close SaveChanges:=0
Set fileWORD = Nothing

objWORD.Quit SaveChanges:=0  'Word object does not close, back checked in Task Manager
Set objWORD = Nothing  'Code hangs up here until instance of Word is ended via Task Manager
```

I'm kind of at a loss, and it may not even be an Excel/Word issue, or more of a OS/Machine issue. But hey, maybe my Google game isn't on point for this issue and someone else has an answer.

**-EDIT #1-**
I have also tested multiple spreadsheets and sub routines and it is persistent throughout. When walking through the code, it will hang up on the line following `objWORD.Quit` until the hidden instance of Word is closed on Task Manager.

**-EDIT #2-**
I have tested this on 4 additional desktops within the company with the following information:
1) Windows 10, 1909, build 18363.836 - Office 2010 **Same Issue**
2) Windows 10, 1909, build 18363.836 - Office 2016 **Same Issue**
3) Windows 10, 1903, build 18362.295 - Office 2013 **No Issue**
4) Windows 10, 1909, build 18363.778 - Office 2010 **No Issue**

My machine runs Windows 10, 1909, build 18363.836 - Office 2013, same OS Build as the other two machines that are having identical symptoms, but with different Office editions.
I am becoming to think this may actually be an OS issue...

**-EDIT #3-**
I tried rolling back my machine to earlier releases of Windows 10, but the issue still persists. I have also tried running the Repair feature on Office 2013. No Luck.
I also had a few Outlook VBA modules, so I tested them. In those I create an EXCEL object in the same manner, as well as a Word object. Interestingly enough, the Excel object behaved as intended, but the Word object still would not `Quit()` and `Close()` as anticipated.
I still cannot find a clear answer as to if this is a Word/Office issue, a Windows issue, or a mixture.

Thanks all for the help, but this may be one of those things where I hope for a fix in a future patch/update.

Comment: Try `fileWord.Close`:`Set fileWord=Nothing`:`objWord.Quit`:`Set objWord=Nothing`. In your initial code, you are clearing the reference to Word, but the reference to the document still exists, which may lead to a reference to Word hanging around.

Comment: I believe the first example is missing the `wdDoNotSaveChanges` enum on both the `Close()` and `Quit()` methods. Since it's not visible, you don't know if a message box "Save changes?" has popped up. The second example simply doesn't make sense why you're creating 4 instances without holding their references and then blindly trying to get their references back.

Comment: @Applecore, I thought of that too after my post. I tried this morning to move the statements around to match your lineup, but still had the same outcome.

Comment: @KostasK. I adjusted my code to include `savechanges:=0` with `Close()` and `Quit()` (I use as few non-basic references as possible since other people within my company use these sheets). I still had the same outcome. Just to be sure no errors/alerts showed, I ran the code again with the Application Word Object visible `objWORD.visible = true`. The visible GUI did close on `objWORD.Quit`, but from task manager, it shifted from the "Apps" top section to the "Background process" section. So it seems `objWORD.Quit` simply closed the GUI of Word, but the process still runs in the background.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an old forgotten instance running in the background?

Comment: @KostasK. When I first encountered the issue, I noticed multiple background instances of Word open. When a particular one was closed (I'm assuming the one bound with the current running code), we were off to the races again. Now I am running just one `Sub` where I particularly noticed the issue, and watching Task Manager create it's one instance of Word, watching the CPU "think" as it does it stuff, and even "thinks' when I issue the `Quit()` method. But then it just sits there, like a stain in a rug. Additionally, thanks for the help thus far - I Don't want my replies to sound curt.

Comment: @KostasK. I am going to test some other `Subs` in which I utilize this to see if I find the same issue and cross compare. So far I've focused only on one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, within the last 2 months, Windows/Microsoft must have come through in an update, and this issue no longer happens...
Can't really pinpoint it to any particular solution unfortunately.

File this one away under "total weirdness, but now it works" issues.

thanks for all who offered assistance, your efforts did not go unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem in powershell and this was my solution:

```
objWORD.Application.Quit () | Out-Null
```